# PHP: DATETIME help

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime, datetime-format

I know there's ample information about datetimes on the internet but I'm having trouble using what I've been seeing.

I have a calander control hooked up to a text box. It takes it in the form 15/11/2010 (british). I use it to query datetime fields in a SQL server db in the format 15/11/2010 00:00:00.

After the capture the dates on postback I pass the values onto my method that attempts to convert the text into time format. When I query for something between 01/01/2010 and 01/07/2010 I get a number of results. When I change this to between 01/01/2010 and 30/10/2010 I get an error. The error is invalid foreach (haven't caught the error yet). I'm guessing its something to do with my formats?

```
function getSupportTicketsbySubIssueAndDate($subissueid, $from, $to){

    $subissueid = $this->ms_escape_string($subissueid);

    $from = date("DD/MM/YY", strtotime($from));
    $to = date("DD/MM/YY", strtotime($to));

    $connection = new Connections();
    $conn = $connection->connectToWarehouse();
    $atid = $_SESSION['saveddata']['autotaskid'];


    $tsql = "SELECT wh_task.task_id, wh_task.task_name, wh_task.task_description, wh_task.task_number, wh_task.reported_by_name, wh_task.create_time, wh_resource.first_name, wh_resource.last_name, wh_task_status.task_status_name ".
            "FROM wh_task_status INNER JOIN (wh_task INNER JOIN wh_resource ON wh_task.assigned_resource_id = wh_resource.resource_id) ON wh_task_status.task_status_id = wh_task.task_status_id ".
            "WHERE (account_id = $atid) AND (subissue_type_id = $subissueid) AND (((wh_task.create_time) Between '$from' And '$to'))".
            "ORDER BY create_time DESC";


    // set up array to hold each of the issue types and the number of tickets in each
    $ticket;

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
    if( $stmt === false)
    {
             echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $x = 0;
    /* Retrieve each row as an associative array and display the results.*/
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
            $ticket[$x][0] = $row['task_name'];
            $ticket[$x][1] = $row['task_description'];
            $ticket[$x][2] = $row['task_number'];
            $ticket[$x][3] = $row['reported_by_name'];
            $ticket[$x][4] = $row['first_name'];
            $ticket[$x][5] = $row['last_name'];
            $ticket[$x][6] = $row['task_status_name'];
            $ticket[$x][7] = $row['create_time'];
            $ticket[$x][8] = $row['task_id'];

            $x++;
    }

    return $ticket;
}
```

Any help most appreciated!

Jonesy

Comment: I think you want to convert your datetime for MySQL as well. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure if you're formatting the dates correctly. You can find all the formatting rules at the bottom through the URL posted

```
date("DD/MM/YY ...
```

That's not gonna work cause that's not how they're formatted in PHP. This:

```
date("d/m/y ...
```

will change the format to DD/MM/YY. :)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: D/m/y will print the day as text though?

Comment: If you need to get the the unix timestamp of a date string, the strtotime($str) function is excellent. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Oh damn my bad, I meant small d :)

Answer (score 1):

date("DD/MM/YY"); would output SATSAT/DECDEC/2010201020102010..
pretty sure you're wanting `date("d/m/Y",...`

Comment: If I put it into this format and choose the 13/01/2010 and 13/11/2010 when I echo the dates after the conversion they show as 01/01/1970 and 01/01/1970

Comment: Then your timestamp is wrong - ie, $form and $to are not parsed correctly by strtotime.